# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "........": syntax error

Tags: python, django, sqlite

windows 7

python 2.7

Django 1.11

I have used Django to develop a website. In the backend I have the sqlite database which have 2 tables. One table accepts the form user submitted, and the other is for comparison. 
Once a form A is submitted by the user, it will be save under table catalog_fw, and the catalog_fw.ODM and catalog_fw.project_name will be compared with the ones in the table  catalog_fw_instance. If one line have the exact same content for catalog_fw.ODM and catalog_fw.project, catalog_fw_instance.level will be combined with A to pass to the an .exe to generate a txtx file.

However, error occurs in this line： `c.execute("catalog_fw_instance.level,......`
`
when I run this python file：

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "catalog_fw_instance": syntax error
```

The code to get sqlite data, compare and pass to the .exe is here:

```
def when_call_exe():
with sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3') as con:
    c = con.cursor()

    #c.execute("catalog_fw_instance.level, SELECT catalog_fw.ODM_name, catalog_fw.project_name, catalog_fw.UAP, catalog_fw.NAP, catalog_fw.LAP, catalog_fw.num_address FROM catalog_fw INNER JOIN catalog_fw_instance ON catalog_fw.ODM_name=catalog_fw_instance.ODM_name AND catalog_fw.project_name=catalog_fw_instance.project_name")
    sql = ("SELECT catalog_fw.ODM_name, catalog_fw.project_name, catalog_fw.UAP, catalog_fw.NAP, catalog_fw.LAP, " +
           "catalog_fw.num_address, catalog_fw_instance.level " +
           "FROM catalog_fw catalog_fw" +
           "INNER JOIN catalog_fw_instance catalog_fw_instanc" +
           "    ON catalog_fw.ODM_name = catalog_fwi.ODM_name AND catalog_fw.project_name = catalog_fw_instance.project_name")
    c.execute(sql)



    print '1:', c.fetchone()
    parameter = c.fetchone()
    print '2', parameter

    #pass to exe
    args = ['.//exe//Test.exe', parameter[0], parameter[1]+parameter[2], parameter[3], parameter[4], parameter[5], parameter[6]]

    output = my_check_output(args)
    if 'SUCCESS' in output:
        filename = output[28:-1]

    else:
        filename = output[8:-1]

    downloadlink = os.path.join('/exe', '%s' % filename)


    #save link to sqlite db

    c.execute('''UPDATE catalog_fw SET download = %s  WHERE 
ODM_Name=parameter[1] AND project_Name=parameter[2] ''' % downloadlink)
```

here shows the 2 tables in the sqlite database

[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIuYz.jpg)
[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPrHX.jpg)

Comment: `cursor#execute` should be passed only a SQLite query, in quotes, AFAIK.  In any case, you need to surround your query with quotes.

Comment: thanks, could you show me the modified code? I still do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, when calling `cursor#execute()` in Python, we should be passing a single string containing the query to be run.  It looks like you are passing one of the select parameters, followed by a query, all together as a single string.  Consider the following version:

```
c = con.cursor()

sql = ("SELECT cf.ODM_name, cf.project_name, cf.UAP, cf.NAP, cf.LAP, " +
       "cf.num_address, cfi.level " +
       "FROM catalog_fw cf " +
       "INNER JOIN catalog_fw_instance cfi " +
       "    ON cf.ODM_name = cfi.ODM_name AND cf.project_name = cfi.project_name")
c.execute(sql)

print(c.fetchone())
parameter = c.fetchone()
```

Comment: thanks, when I use your code, syntax error disappears. But now error occurs:  c.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: catalog_fw

Comment: Can you run the above query directly on SQLite without any error?  This is the first thing I would try.  The error message is saying that this table does not exist.

Comment: Your should check the values of `parameter[]`, to make sure the record you are getting back is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks , now it was fixed, but new error occurs in this line：     c.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: catalog_fw.ODM_name

Comment: I won't be of much help, because my main expertise is with the SQL query, not the Python code, and the former should be working, assuming all your tables and columns actually exist.

Comment: Thanks, as shown in table1 and 2, all the table and column exist using DB browser. But I do not know why no such column error occurs.